# Different ProductName and Title for Visual Studio Setup project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-setup-proje, custom-installation

I am creating an installer using Visual Studio Setup Project (2010). I need the string that is displayed in the title bar of the installation wizard be different from the Product name, but there seems to be no option for that. There is an option named Title but that has a different purpose. Does anybody know a way for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is way to do this by changing anything in Visual Studio. You'd need to use an MSI file editor (such as Orca from the Windows Kit) to edit the MSI file. Open the MSI file with Orca and go to the Control table, the WelcomeForm entries will have one with a BannerText control. The text for this will start with ..... Welcome to the [ProductName] Setup Wizard .....  and just replace [ProductName] with your new text.

The properties window of the Welcome form in the setup project will lket you use a different BannerBitmap if you want to change that too.

To automate changes like this you'd need to know something about the SQL commands that can be used (with VBScript) to update MSI files.

There are some examples here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372021(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368562(v=vs.85).aspx

and there is a script called WiRunSql.vbs in the Windows kit/SDK that takes a path to an MSI and a SQL command. Basically you're going to update the Control table where Dialog_ is WelcomeDialog and Control = BannerText and change the Text value to a copy of what's in there already with your text.

Comment: thanks, I need to integrate this in an automated build process. Is it possible to use Orca in command line and do what you can do via GUI?